# BulkCopy not copying read data

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I am copying rows from an ODBC connection to a SQL database server. Ideally, it should copy every row across to the server specified by a query. The correct rows are read and can be accessed from the reader using `while(readerODBC.read())`. However, when writing to the server using `bulkCopy.WriteToServer()`, no rows are transferred.

```
connectionODBC.Open();
using ( readerODBC = getSourceCmdODBC( connectionODBC , columnListODBC , tableName ).ExecuteReader() )
{
    connectionSQL.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction transaction = connectionSQL.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionSQL, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction)) 
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo." + dbTableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240000;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(readerODBC);
        }
    }
}
connectionSQL.Close();
connectionODBC.Close();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code.  My first thought is that you should really separate out the two process of reading vs doing the bulk copy back to the database. Right now they are all mashed together. Without stepping over your code in debug mode, it's hard to know what's going wrong here.  Some things I would look for.... does 'dbTableName' have a value?   Does 'readerODBC' have any content?

Comment: Just to clarify my previous statement... Google "Single Responsibility". I would re-write this code with two methods. The first method does nothing but build and populate your reader. The second method does nothing but the bulk copy.  Keep them clean and separate from each other.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will change this and see if the problem persists

Comment: Ok updated, I am currently getting the error 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 4815.'

Comment: re: no rows being transferred - You're doing the bulk copy within an external transaction but you don't seem to be calling `transaction.Commit()`